# Select after multiple union

Tags: sql, union

i need to select distinct value from a multiple union.
I nee to use union on multiple table on different databases.
But i i try to use this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name ((SELECT name FROM tab1) UNION (SELECT name FROM tab2))
```

i have this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT name FROM tab2 )' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use "distinct". UNION gives you the distinct result already.

```
SELECT name FROM tab1
UNION
SELECT name FROM tab2
```

This give you the correct result.By the way, if you want to fetch data from different database you need to use db name.Please refer following for this;

```
SELECT name FROM db1.tab1
UNION
SELECT name FROM db2.tab2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM (
    SELECT name FROM tab1 
    UNION 
    SELECT name FROM tab2
) TABLEALIAS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ((SELECT name FROM tab1) UNION (SELECT name FROM tab2)) as sth
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `FROM`, and an alias for the inner result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM (
  SELECT name FROM tab1
  UNION
  SELECT name FROM tab2
) x
```

However, you don't need the `DISTINCT` there at all, the `UNION` already removes duplicates.